# Graphs not showing up on Hugo blogdown site

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am having trouble getting graphs that I render through .Rmd files to show up on my github.io page. I create the .Rmd file on my computer, use `blogdown::serve_site()` to create the .html file. The site renders fine with all graphs on my computer. There is a folder for each .html page that has graphs in it, in .png form, on my computer, under `/static/portfolio`. When I go to put it on github.io, any pictures that I have linked to show up, but all graphs that I have created do not. I figure it is an issue of setting a path correctly, but I cannot figure it out myself. I am using the creative portfolio theme if that makes a difference.

You can find my source code [here](https://github.com/marissabarlaz/marissabarlaz.github.io/tree/master).

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot/code (where the issue is) to understand better?